# Find the most frequent character in text

Tags: go

I need to implement a package with interface with methods that take text file and performs analysis on it - counts the total amount of characters and finds the most frequent symbol and word. To find the most frequent character I loop through each rune in the text, convert it to string and append it as a key to `map`. The value is an incremented counter which counts how often this character occurs in the given text. Now I'm stuck a little with the following problem -- I can't figure out how to get the key with the highest value in my map. Here's the code:

```
package textscanner

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
    "unicode/utf8"
    "strconv"
)

// Initializing my scanner
type Scanner interface {
    countChar(text string) int

    frequentSym(text string) // Return value is not yet implemented

    Scan()

    Run()
}

/* method counting characters */
func countChar(sc Scanner, text string) int { ... }

func frequentSym(sc Scanner, text string) {
    // Make a map with string key and integer value
    symbols := make(map[string] int)

    // Iterate through each char in text
    for _, sym := range text {
        // Convert rune to string
        char := strconv.QuoteRune(sym)
        // Set this string as a key in map and assign a counter value 
        count := symbols[char]

        if count == symbols[char] {
            // increment the value
            symbols[char] = count + 1
        } else {
            symbols[char] = 1
        }
    }
}
```

So, basically I need to find a pair with the highest `int` value and return a `string` key that corresponds to it, that is the most frequent character in text

Comment: Why do you convert the rune to string, couldn't you just use rune as the map key, ie `map[rune] int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over the map:

```
maxK := ""
maxV := 0
for k, v := range symbols {
    if v > maxV {
        maxV = v
        maxK = k
    }
}
// maxK is the key with the maximum value.
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But it appears that the most frequent character in my text is ' ' (i.e. space), is there any way to exclude it from my map?

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 Just `delete(symbols, " ")`?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Ainar-G answer, if there is a possibility that your map could contain multiple keys that occur the same number of times, then @Ainar-G code could return different results every time because Go maps are inherently unordered; in other words, the first key in your map to have a value higher then all previous values becomes the highest key, but you don't always know whether that value will occur first in the map. See [this](https://goplay.tools/snippet/1oqj9GVSfUk) as an example.

In order for the code to be deterministic, you will need to address the case where two keys have the same value. A simple implementation would be to do a string comparison if the value is the same.

```
maxK := ""
maxV := 0
for k, v := range symbols {
    if v > maxV || (v == maxV && k < maxK) {
        maxV = v
        maxK = k
    }
}
```